# How do I use this library

Tags: android, github, shared-libraries

Sorry for the really basic question, but I cant find a straight forward answer.

I have tried importing this library into my android studio project as I want to be able to view pdfs from within the application:

https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

by adding the line:

compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'

to my gradle.

The thing is, I haven't got a clue how to use it. I tried to copy the sample, but there are loads of errors. As an example

```
@ViewById
PDFView pdfView;
```

The @ViewById comes up saying can not resolve symbol '@ViewById'

I know I'm asking fundamental stuff and will need to research to get a full understanding but can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Comment: based on [this](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/blob/master/android-pdfview-sample/build.gradle) which you have clearly not read nor researched, the hint is in the section `dependencies`, You need to use that in your project.

Comment: There is a sample project there as well!!

Comment: I added the dependencies but am getting this error when I try to sync:Error:(31, 0) Project with path ':android-pdfview' could not be found in project ':app'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You integrate the PDFVIEW into your xml layout:

```
<com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

From then on you can access the element from code in any method of an activity exposing a layout, e.g.: in your MainActivity.java:

```
String assetFileName = "about.pdf"; //The name of the asset to open
int pageNumber = 0; //Start at the first page

PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfview); //Fetch the view
pdfView.fromAsset(assetFileName) //Fill it with data
            .defaultPage(pageNumber) //Set default page number
            .onPageChange(null) //PageChangeListener
            .load();
```

- assetFileName = the name of the asset you want to open. The PDF-File must be placed in main/assets/ as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) . Make Sure you have an "about.pdf" in your asset folder, otherwise the code example will not work.
- pageNumber = the page that should be shown at the beginning. You can just set it to 0 if you want the PdfViewer to start at the beginning of the .pdf file.

Comment: Its more of a gradle issue the OP is facing, nevertheless a good answer :)

Comment: my snippet should work without the "@ViewById" line, so i think it could help him to understand what the @ViewById statement is doing..

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. It isstillnot resolving assetFileName or pageNumber

Comment: Just added some info and included some fixes. "assetFileName " and "pageNumber" should be clear now.